# Magento2: How to check record before save record in table?

Tags: magento2, database, resource-model, savedata

I am adding the barcode with product SKU and product ID in a table using below code:-

File Path: /app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/Model/ResourceModel/Custom.php

```
public function generateBarcodes($object, $attribute, $barcode, $_product)
    {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $barcodeModel = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Barcode');

        $data = array(
            'barcode' => $barcode,
            'product_id' => $_product->getId(),
            'qty' => 1,
            'product_sku' => $_product->getSku(),
            'supplier_code' => '',
            'history_id' => 0000
        );      

        $barcodeModel->setData($data);
        $barcodeModel->save(); 
    }
```

but I want to stop duplicate record in table, Please let me know how to achieve this in above code.

My table structure:-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the **load** method for checking, like:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$barcodeModel = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Barcode');
$barcodeModel->load($barcode, 'barcode');
if (!$barcodeModel->getId()) {
    $data = array(
        'barcode' => $barcode,
        'product_id' => $_product->getId(),
        'qty' => 1,
        'product_sku' => $_product->getSku(),
        'supplier_code' => '',
        'history_id' => 0000
    );

    $barcodeModel->setData($data);
    $barcodeModel->save();
}
```

You can modify the following code by using what you want to check against:

```
$barcodeModel->load($barcode, 'barcode');
```

***Note: use repository for CRUD operation.***

***Warning: Don't use object manage, use DI instead***

Comment: Thanks @sohel, solution working for me.

Comment: Why add notes and warnings as opposed to fixing the answer? Seems silly.